# Is there some plugin for eclipse which shows a minified outline of the source?

Tags: eclipse, plugins, ide

E.g. Komodo IDE has this feature:

[image: Komodo IDE]

Can be really useful for getting an overview of a big file.
Anyone knows something similar for eclipse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes its there. Look this [overview-plugin](http://sandipchitale.blogspot.in/2013/02/overview-plugin-for-eclipse.html). This plugin shows the **overview** of the current text editor in the **Overview** view. Also the tooltip shows the line under the cursor. Also note that you can control the **zoom level** in **overview** view.

Screen shots:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The general way of providing that kind of view (not *exactly* a minified view, but as useful) is through an outline.

For JSON, you would need an [eclipse JSON plugin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/eclipsejsonedit/), which has a JSON outline dedicated view:

[image: http://a.fsdn.com/con/app/proj/eclipsejsonedit/screenshots/217750.jpg]

Answer (score -1):

You can use the **Quick Outline** feature of many editors in Eclipse to get a pop-up, easily navigable outline of the file's contents. Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> (<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> on Mac).

To bring up the "normal" persistent **Outline View**, open **Quick Access** with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> (<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> on Mac) then type *outline* and select it from the list.

Comment: This is not an answer. In outline view we can see `ONLY the method and field names` NOT the method body/content.